Apple CarPlay add image into Alert (CPAlertTemplate)
I want to add image into apple CarPlay Default CPAlertTemplate function.
Here is my code:
I want to add image along with alert title, description.
Heading

  func updateCarPlayTemplate(title: String) {
        guard let interfaceController = carPlayInterfaceController else { return }
        
        // Dismiss any existing template
        interfaceController.dismissTemplate(animated: false) {, in
            // Define the title and description
            let title = title
            // Define the title variants to include the description
            let titleVariants = [title]
            // Define the actions
            let okAction = CPAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
                // Handle OK action
                interfaceController.dismissTemplate(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            // Create and present the alert template
            let alertTemplate = CPAlertTemplate(titleVariants: titleVariants, actions: [okAction])
            interfaceController.presentTemplate(alertTemplate, animated: true)
            
            // Dismiss the template automatically after 3 seconds
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                interfaceController.dismissTemplate(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }


Please check alertTemplate.tabImage is helpful ?

CarPlay UI is quite limited. CPAlertTemplate does not have an ability to show an image

I have used tabImage with CPAlertTemplate but its not working, getting error:
"Instance member 'tabImage' cannot be used on type 'CPAlertTemplate
